# Android read in large String from file

Tags: java, android

In my application, when it loads up, it makes a web call which retrieves a JSON string. I want to store this JSON string to the phone so the application won't crash if the user loses connection. JSON string is required to set the text of the application. So I am doing this

```
    File myDir = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());

                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(myDir + "/jsonMain.txt");
                fw.write(sJsonMain);
                fw.close();
```

And then to retrieve it I am doing this

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                            myDir + "/jsonMain.txt"));
                    sStoredJSON = br.readLine();
```

It works fine with other JSON strings, however it is not with the Large JSON string. I checked the log and it says this

> 04-26 10:00:44.511: I/global(893): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.

Could someone please tell me how else I can read in a large string like this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: use fileinputStream class and read byte by byte and append it to string builder ........

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think to do this before, far easier way of doing it lol. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                        myDir + "/jsonMain.txt"), 8); // or a higher value than 8
sStoredJSON = br.readLine();
```

Comment: I tried this method, that message about buffer size no longer appears, so I tried printing it out, but no luck :@.

Comment: you should use (1024 * 8) as value = 8kB.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the buffer size on BufferedReader [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#BufferedReader%28java.io.Reader,%20int%29), so you can use the previous File object to ascertain the file [lenght](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29) and create the buffer size accordingly.